# Retrieve existing resource data using AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I need to retrieve existing data/properties of a given resource by using an AWS Cloudformation template. Is it possible? If it is how can I do it?

Example 1:

- Output: Security Group ID which allows traffic on port 22

Example 2:

- Output: Instance ID which use default VPC

Comment: Please Edit your question and describe in more detail what you mean by "retrieve existing resource data". What are you wanting in the output? Can you provide some examples? I suspect that what you seek can be obtained via AWS Config, but I'd need to understand your needs better before making this suggestion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hope my examples help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AWS CloudFormation** is used to deploy infrastructure from a template in a repeatable manner. It cannot provide information on any resources created by any methods *outside* of CloudFormation.

Your requirements seem more relevant to [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html):

> AWS Config provides a detailed view of the configuration of AWS resources in your AWS account. This includes how the resources are related to one another and how they were configured in the past so that you can see how the configurations and relationships change over time.
>
> An AWS resource is an entity you can work with in AWS, such as an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instance, an Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) volume, a security group, or an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).

Using your examples, AWS Config can list EC2 instances and any resources that are connected to the instances, such as Security Groups and VPCs. You can easily click-through these relationship and view the configurations. It is also possible to view how these configurations have changed over time, such as:

- When EC2 instance changed state (eg stopped, running)
- When rules changed on Security Groups

Alternatively, you can simply **make API calls to AWS services** to obtain the current configuration of resources, such as calling `DescribeInstances` to obtain a list of Amazon EC2 instances and their configurations.

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein for this detailed answer. I'll try using AWS Config.